# Being logged out when using Hazelcast distrubuted sessions in Jhipster

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster, hazelcast

**Context:**

I have created a Monolithic application using Jhipster (v4.1.0) and included the following features:

- HTTP Session Authentication (stateful, default Spring Security mechanism)
- Hibernate 2nd level cache?: Yes, with HazelCast (distributed cache, for multiple nodes)
- Clustered HTTP sessions using Hazelcast

When I run a single instance of the application everything works as expected. I can login, and use the application without being logged out.

**Problem and what I have tried:**

However when I start a second instance of the application (using docker-compose scale) I experience the following:

- When the second instance starts up I can see the Hazelcast instances connecting successfully

> Members [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEwNF.png) {
>
> ```
>   Member [172.18.0.3]:5701 - 782c21f9-5065-4bfc-bc13-23dfb42cf6f7
>   Member [172.18.0.5]:5701 - d4fcf306-e20a-497b-a6b8-000341881419 this
> }
> ```

- I can successfully access the application on either of the instances
- I can login on either instance and use the application on that instance without being logged out
- When I switch over to the other instance, I am logged out on both instances

My initial thought was the Clustered HTTP sessions using Hazelcast was not working correctly, however when I implemented a simple controller to check the session details (exactly as suggested in [this example](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/hazelcast-integration/springboot-http)) I found the following:

- I access the first instance and am given an access denied error
- I login on the first instance, my controller now shows me my session details, I can refresh the page while staying logged in, keeping the same session ID and the counter variable on the session increases:
  [image]
- I access the second instance and immediately given an access denied error
- I access the first instance again and am given an access denied error (Im definitely logged out)
- If I login on the first instance again, my session ID remains the SAME 
  and the counter is still counting
- If I login on the second instance, my session ID is the same as on the first instance, and the counter continues from where it left off on the first

My conclusion is that the Clustered HTTP sessions using Hazelcast is working correctly. I have also implemented a load balancer (HAProxy) between the two instances, however when I login Im immediately logged out again. I later updated the HAProxy to make use of sticky sessions, which then allows the application to function, however then when the instance that is handling a session fails (stopped) the user is logged out and not moved over to the other instance, defeating the purpose of the distrubuted sessions.

**Finally, my questions:**

- Am I wrong in thinking that the authentication should be maintained because the session is shared between instances? (i.e. is something other the session responsible for keeping authentication)
- Why am I being logged out?
- Where should I look to try and debug the issue?

**Update**

I have uploaded a repository containing the full application:

- https://github.com/tfoxcroft/jhipster-issue

Only changes made after generating with jhipster were to src/main/docker/app.yml to add the loadbalancer, and to add the controller and html to view session details at

- http://localhost:PORT/view-session

Application is started with

`./mvnw package -Pprod docker:build
docker-compose -f src/main/docker/app.yml up -d`

And scaled with

```
`docker-compose -f src/main/docker/app.yml scale jhipster3-app=2`
```

Comment: Ive found that I can set a parameter in WebConfigurer to change hazelcasts  sticky-session to false (was true). I thought this would then match what the load-balancer is set to, but results in the same behaviour, the session seems to work fine, but still not staying authenticated.

Comment: I would expect that to be an issue inside jhipster, maybe based on the authentication works. Unfortunately I have no further knowledge with jhipster but I would say it might make sense to open an issue in their bugtracker. My personal guess would be, the authentication (principal, whatever) is not stored in the session but in the server and therefore is lost but just a gut feeling / weird guess.

Comment: @noctarius thanks for the suggestion, I will look into that